# How to make good view with bootstrap and html?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a little problem.I'm still, learn to program and I don't have very good knowledge.
I'm trying to make view like this:
[image]

In this view items are located very evenly.
In my view items are not looking good:
[image]

Why i have to repair in my code to look like this online shop view?
My code is here:

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>item/single.html"><h3><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h3></a>
            <?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) :?>
            <small class="post-date">Posted on: <?php echo $post['created_at']; ?> in <strong><?php echo $post['name']; ?></strong></small>
            <?php endif ?>

            <div class="zoom-in">
            <img class="post-thumb" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/images/posts/<?php echo $post['post_image']; ?>">
            </div>
            <?php echo word_limiter($post['body'],10); ?>
            <b></b>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger addcart" productid="<?php echo $post['id'] ?>" value="Добави в количката">
            <p><a class="btn btn-link" href="<?php echo site_url('/posts/'.$post['slug']); ?>">Read more</a></p>
            </div>

            <?php endforeach; } ?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please also  include tags as php

Comment: What exactly do you want it to do that it's not already doing? Is the whole problem just that the height of the image on the left is not the same as the height of the other 2 images?

Answer (score 0):

resize Image Like this

```css
html, body {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
body {
  margin: 20px;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image-grid {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto 35px;
  max-width: 920px;
}

.svg-image-grid {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto 35px;
  max-width: 920px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

/** Screen readers only class from Bootstrap */

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  border: 0;
}

/** Actual code examples */

/** Background */

.image-bg {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
          flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
}
.image-bg-placeholder {
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

/** Object-fit */

.image-fit {
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
          flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
}
.image-fit-placeholder {
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.image-fit-img {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

/** Absolute positioning */

.image {
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
          flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
}
.image-placeholder {
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.image-img {
  left: 50%;
  max-height: 150%;
  max-width: 177%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/** SVG */

.image-svg {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-bottom: calc(25% - 10px);
  position: relative;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
}
.image-svg svg {
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

/** Responsive grid */

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .image,
  .image-fit,
  .image-bg,
  .image-svg {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
  .image-svg {
    padding-bottom: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Techniques to crop and resize images with CSS</h1>

<h2>Image as a background</h2>

<div class="image-grid">

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704491300" class="image-bg" style="background-image:url(https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2809/33704491300_1df01dd919_z_d.jpg)" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-bg-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-bg-img sr-only" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2809/33704491300_1df01dd919_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image as a background example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/33704488370" class="image-bg" style="background-image:url(https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2848/33704488370_9572b9d270_z_d.jpg)" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-bg-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-bg-img sr-only" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2848/33704488370_9572b9d270_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image as a background example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088934825" class="image-bg" style="background-image:url(https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3947/34088934825_0acfe80a04_z_d.jpg)" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-bg-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-bg-img sr-only" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3947/34088934825_0acfe80a04_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image as a background example" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/teroauralinna/34088930595" class="image-bg" style="background-image:url(https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3956/34088930595_2b84cec168_z_d.jpg)" target="_blank">
    <img class="image-bg-placeholder" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="" />
    <img class="image-bg-img sr-only" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3956/34088930595_2b84cec168_z_d.jpg" alt="Cropped image as a background example" />
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: But I'm using PHP. How I can do this with my code? My images come from database.

Comment: When php runs it produces html so you can use css like you would in any normal html page.

Comment: Well, you could just add css `div.zoom-in { height: 200px; }` so all the image container divs have the same height. It's really hard to help you because you have just said "I have problem with css formatting" but haven't specified what the problem you are having actually is.